# How do I set up an 802.1X infrastructure for use with OS X and iPads?

Tags: mac-osx-server, certificate-authority, radius, ad-certificate-services, ipad

At my workplace I have been tasked with setting up machine certificate based 802.1X wireless authentication for our Apple devices. It seems like on the client side this will be handled by Profiles (specifically a System Profile as it is the device we wish to issue certificates to, not a user as devices are not assigned to single users).

However I have not been able to figure out how to set up the other required components - specifically a RADIUS service and a Mac certificate authority. I found that Keychain Access in its Certificate Assistant has the ability to create a Certificate Authority, but is this suitable for enterprise use? Does it link in to Open Directory?

Alternatively, if it is easier, how can I connect Macs to our Windows based 802.1X infrastructure? We have a Server 2008 R2 Certificate Services and Network Policy Services (RADIUS) server which already authenticates our Windows clients. I attempted to follow these instructions from Apple (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5357) but was unable to get them to work (when attempting to install the profile, a client failed to be able to acquire a certificate - step 10 in the Computer certificate section).

We are running OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion (though we would like a solution that will also work with the new 10.9 Mavericks as we anticipate transitioning to that at some point due to it being free) and we have a Mac with OS X Server installed which hosts Open Directory and is also bound to our Windows Active Directory.

Comment: Here is a decent set of instructions for configuring RADIUS on OS X 10.8 and later. GUI configuration was removed from Server.app but the service is very much there: http://jedda.me/2012/11/configuring-basic-radius-os-108-server/